# const reference argument of constexpr function: gcc/msvc vs clang/icc

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14, language-lawyer

I've discovered that calling a constexpr static method using a constant reference argument leads to an error "expression is not an integral constant" for both clang and icc, but not for gcc or msvc (https://godbolt.org/z/PewOVc):

```
struct S
{
  static constexpr bool ok() { return true; }
};

constexpr void ff(const S &s) // OK for everyone if not a ref
{  
  static_assert(s.ok(), "oops!"); // ERROR clang/icc, OK gcc/msvc  
  static_assert(S::ok(), "oops!"); // OK for everyone
}
```

If argument is not a reference then code compiles by any of these compilers. Who is right/correct here?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard [disqualifies](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const) evaluated id-expressions that have reference types from participating in constant-expressions (unless some more constraints are met, which is not the case for this code).

However gcc seems to ignore this rule. The same result (gcc accepts, clang rejects) can be obtained with this simplified function:

```
constexpr void ff(const int &s) 
{  
  static_assert((s, true), "oops!"); 
}
```

So the problem has nothing to do with static member functions. My interpretation is that this is a gcc bug.

I did not check msvc, maybe the bug is different there but it's still wrong.